# Ubuntu 15.10 has noise effect when focusing

Tags: 15.10, window, focus

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and choose another window on my current view-port, this window is "bouncing". Making it a little smaller, then stay normal.

It's not very nice, and noising me. How I can turn this "jumping" effects off?

Ok, I'm trying to be more clear. Translated by Google.

I do not like the effect when the focus of the window when I switch between the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. The focused window first to get a little less, and then abruptly returned to normal size. 
How do I get rid of this effect? 
I wish that when you switch between windows, their size has not changed.

Also I record video, when I tab <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> all windows stay smaller, and when I focus window and relase <kbd>Alt</kbd> - it's bouncing.

https://youtu.be/sh7shNOmzJA

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/794706/edit) your question to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @grooveplex, sorry english not my native language. What is not  clarify in my text?

Comment: You should make your question more clear and easier to understand, see as well [how to ask a good question](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:
In CompizConfig Settings Manager -> Window management -> Application Switcher -> General ->  Zoom -> Set to 0. And zooming effect will be disabled. Also set speed to 20 for more comfort switch between application.